# Is this "DI" structure impossible, or should I look for a bug?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection

### Explanation:

As a personal project, I'm trying to create my own lightweight version of Dependency Injection for JavaScript - Some would probably disagree with calling this DI because it has no interfaces, but I arrived at the conclusion that interfaces were overkill in JS since we can so easily type check. I have looked at the source of Angular, but I just feel like the complexity there may be overkill for my projects, and I'm interested in attempting my own for a learning experience anyway.

### Question:

**My question is, fundamentally, is the syntax I'm trying to implement impossible or not?**

I'll explain my goal for the syntax, then provide the error and code snippet, and below that I'll post the full code.

### Goal for Syntax:

I'd like the creation of a component, and injection of dependencies to work like this, where everything is a component, and anything can be a dependency. I created scope with a string path, using `"/scopeName/subScopeName:componentName"` to select a scope, so that code users can select the scope while defining the component in a simple way, using a `":"` to select a component from the scope.

```
var JHTML = new Viziion('JHTML');
JHTML.addScope('/generate');

/* ...snip - see full code for the process component - snip ... */

JHTML.addComponent('/generate:init', function (jsonInput, process) {
  var html = process(jsonInput);
  return html;
}).inject([null, '/generate:process']);
```

The `inject` function just takes an array of component paths in the order the component's arguments are expected. `null` can be used to skip, allowing direct argument input instead, as shown above.

I also have something I call hooks, which are components stored in a certain place, and then there's a function `returnUserHandle` which will return an object consisting of just the hooks, so all of the functions are hidden in closures, and you can feed the code user just the usable methods, clean and easy, and can produce the final product as a library without the wiring, no need for my DI framework as a dependency. Hopefully that makes sense.

### Error:

Right now, running the code (which is a very simple library to generate HTML by parsing a JSON structure) I get the error that `process` is undefined in the line `var html = process(jsonInput);`. I was having trouble understanding whether this is a fundamental design problem, or just a bug. Maybe this syntax is not possible, I'm hoping you can tell me.

### Code:

Here's the code, and [a link to the JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/mefedomeme/edit?js,console).

```js
/* Dependency Injection Framework - viziion.js */

function Viziion(appName) {
  if (typeof appName == 'string') {
    var that = this;
    this.name = appName;
    this.focus = null;
    this.scope = {
      '/': {
        'subScopes': {},
        'components': {}
      }
    };
    this.hooks = {};

    this.addScope = function(scopeName) {
      if (typeof scopeName == 'string') {
        var scopeArray = scopeName.split('/');
        var scope = that.scope['/'];
        for (var i = 0; i < scopeArray.length; i++) {
          if (scopeArray[i] !== "") {
            if (scope.subScopes[scopeArray[i]]) {
              scope = scope.subScopes[scopeArray[i]];
            } else {
              scope.subScopes[scopeArray[i]] = {
                'subScopes': {},
                'components': {}
              };
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        throw 'Scope path must be a string.';
      }
      return that;
    };

    this.addComponent = function(componentName, func) {
      if (typeof componentName == 'string') {
        var scopeArray = componentName.split(':');
        if (scopeArray.length == 2) {
          var scope = that.scope['/'];
          var scopeName = scopeArray[1];
          scopeArray = scopeArray[0].split('/');
          for (var i = 0; i < scopeArray.length; i++) {
            if (scopeArray[i] !== "") {
              if ((i + 1) === scopeArray.length) {
                scope.components[scopeName] = func;
                that.focus = scope.components[scopeName];
              } else if (scope.subScopes[scopeArray[i]]) {
                scope = scope.subScopes[scopeArray[i]];
              } else {
                throw 'Scope path is invalid.';
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          throw 'Path does not include a component.';
        }
      } else {
        throw 'Component path must be a string1.';
      }
      return that;
    };

    this.returnComponent = function(componentName, callback) {
      if (typeof componentName == 'string') {
        var scopeArray = componentName.split(':');
        if (scopeArray.length == 2) {
          var scope = that.scope['/'];
          var scopeName = scopeArray[1];
          scopeArray = scopeArray[0].split('/');
          for (var i = 0; i < scopeArray.length; i++) {
            if (scopeArray[i] !== "") {
              if ((i + 1) === scopeArray.length) {
                //console.log('yep1');
                //console.log(scope.components[scopeName]);
                callback(scope.components[scopeName]);
              } else if (scope.subScopes[scopeArray[i]]) {
                scope = scope.subScopes[scopeArray[i]];
              } else {
                throw 'Scope path is invalid.';
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          throw 'Path does not include a component.';
        }
      } else {
        throw 'Component path must be a string2.';
      }
    };

    this.addHook = function(hookName, func) {
      if (typeof hookName == 'string') {
        that.hooks[hookName] = func;
        that.focus = that.hooks[hookName];
      } else {
        throw 'Hook name must be a string.';
      }
      return that;
    };

    this.inject = function(dependencyArray) {
      if (dependencyArray) {
        var args = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < dependencyArray.length; i++) {
          if (dependencyArray[i] !== null) {
            that.returnComponent(dependencyArray[i], function(dependency) {
              args.push(dependency);
            });
          }
        }
        console.log(that.focus);
        that.focus.apply(null, args);
        return that;
      }
    };

    this.returnUserHandle = function() {
      return that.hooks;
    };

  } else {
    throw 'Viziion name must be a string.';
  }
}

/* JSON HTML Generator - A Simple Library Using Viziion */

var JHTML = new Viziion('JHTML');

JHTML.addScope('/generate');

JHTML.addComponent('/generate:process', function(children) {
  var html = [];
  var loop = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      if (children[i].tag) {
        html.push('<' + tag + '>');
        if (children[i].children) {
          loop();
        }
        html.push('</' + tag + '>');
        return html;
      } else {
        throw '[JHTML] Bad syntax: Tag type is not defined on node.';
      }
    }
  };
}).inject();

JHTML.addComponent('/generate:init', function(jsonInput, process) {
  console.log(process);
  var html = process(jsonInput);
  return html;
}).inject([null, '/generate:process']);

JHTML.addHook('generate', function(jsonInput, init) {
  var html = init(jsonInput);
  return html;
}).inject([null, '/generate:init']);

handle = JHTML.returnUserHandle();

/* HTML Generator Syntax - Client */

var htmlChunk = [{
  tag: '!DOCTYPEHTML'
}, {
  tag: 'html',
  children: [{
    tag: 'head',
    children: []
  }, {
    tag: 'body',
    children: []
  }]
}];

console.log(handle.generate(htmlChunk));
```

Comment: It's a bug, there's nothing wrong with your concept.

Comment: relating the `.inject()` call to the previous `.addComponent()` call seems to be the hard part in your implementation.

Comment: @Bergi I intend to do it via a `focus` property on the library object, assigned when creating the component, and adding a method `focusComponent` in case someone wants to inject separately from the chain. Maybe you understood that, and were saying there's difficulty/complication making it work that way?

Comment: Anyway, glad this is just a bug :) Ill find it.

Comment: Ah, didn't spot that. But the problem seems to be that you're assigning to `focus` in a loop, where the last "scope" would overwrite the previous ones.

Comment: I'd recommend `addComponent: function(componentName, func) { return {inject: function(dependencyArray) { /* actuall processing of everything here */ }}; }` as a pattern for the fluent interface.

Comment: @Bergi I looked into the loop thing, and I'm a bit confused about what you said. It seems to me the logic `if ((i + 1) === scopeArray.length) {
                scope.components[scopeName] = func;
                that.focus = scope.components[scopeName]; 
              }` ensures that the `focus` method can only be used once per invocation of the `addComponent` method, since it should only run when the loop completes.

Comment: OK, I didn't try enough to understand to your code :-) Forget what I said then. However that might be a sign that you should simplify it ;-P

Comment: @Bergi yes, as soon as I figure out my bug, Ill be taking it to Code Review.SE :) Thanks for the suggestion, ill check that out too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is the syntax I'm trying to implement impossible or not?

It's absolutely possible, and I'm sure with a bit of bugfixing it'd work just fine.

What you're describing is essentially the same as [Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD)](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) which is used extensively for handling code dependencies.

Rather than continuing to pursue your own version of the same concept, I recommend that you give requirejs a try and follow the existing standards with your projects.

Comment: Yeah I've looked into Require. Basically, I feel not only does a custom library add flexibility based on your needs vs design complexity, but also as a relatively new programmer, I'll benefit from developing the various library types from the inside out, to make sure I really understand the language and its structural possibilities, bad parts, good parts, etc.